# Xamarin Forms dbContext MigrateAsync crash

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I Have built my App using an older device which is running Android 7, it is working fine. When I tried to deploy and debug on my Galaxy S9. I step through the code and it seems it always crashes when I get to Entity Framework dbConext when I try to create the Sqllite database it DbContext using  await Database.MigrateAsync(); I even put a try catch block to see if an exception bubbled up to cause this error.
in the Output this is the only errors I see

> =================================================================     Native Crash Reporting
>   ================================================================= Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
>   error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
>
> ## application.
>
> =================================================================     Basic Fault Adddress Reporting
>   ================================================================= Memory around native instruction pointer (0x7532505678):0x7532505668 
>   00 1c 40 b9 c0 03 5f d6 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91  ..@...*..{......
>   0x7532505678  08 20 40 b9 a8 00 c8 37 88 01 e0 37 00 00 40 f9  .
>   @....7...7..@. 0x7532505688  fd 7b c1 a8 c0 03 5f d6 60 08 00 b0 01 0a
>   00 f0  .{....*.`....... 0x7532505698  03 0a 00 f0 00 24 06 91 21 80 08
>   91 63 8c 0a 91  .....$..!...c...
>
> 05-30 10:46:45.575 D/Mono    (20095): AOT: image
>   'System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.so" not found 05-30 10:46:45.576 D/Mono
>   (20095): AOT: image
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d16-1/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-arm64-v8a-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm64/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.so'
>   not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d16-1/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-arm64-v8a-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm64/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.so"
>   not found 05-30 10:46:45.576 D/Mono    (20095): Config attempting to
>   parse: 'System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.config'. 05-30 10:46:45.576
>   D/Mono    (20095): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d16-1/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-arm64-v8a-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Extensions/System.Runtime.Extensions.config'.
>   05-30 10:46:45.576 D/Mono    (20095): Assembly Ref addref
>   Remotion.Linq[0x7532836600] ->
>   System.Runtime.Extensions[0x7526754000]: 2 05-30 10:46:45.576 D/Mono
>   (20095): Loading reference 0 of System.Runtime.Extensions.dll asmctx
>   DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e 05-30 10:46:45.576 D/Mono    (20095):
>   Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Extensions[0x7526754000] ->
>   mscorlib[0x754110a280]: 100 05-30 10:46:45.720 D/Mono    (20095):
>   Loading reference 8 of
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.salesapp/files/.**override**/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.dll
>   asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Remotion.Linq, Version=2.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fee00910d6e5f53b 05-30 10:46:45.720
>   D/Mono    (20095): Assembly Ref addref
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite[0x75411bad00] ->
>   Remotion.Linq[0x7532836600]: 4

Is there some dll version issues I need to resolve for newer phones?